# cannot invoke intilizer for type item with no arguments

Tags: swift, swift3

[image]

Shifting to Swift 3 from the older version the above works for the older versions but finding it difficult to implement in this newer version of swift

Comment: Please don't show images of your code – copy and paste the actual relevant portion of the code into the question, along with any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an optional `var item` then use next

```
var item: Item?
```

Comment: @RinkeshGorasia so mark it as correct answer :))